# C++ Compiler Error: P1LinkedList.cpp:145: error: call of overloaded ‘to_string(int&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I'm implementing a linked list. I'm getting the error:

```
P1LinkedList.cpp:145: error: call of overloaded ‘to_string(int&)’ is ambiguous
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2604: note: candidates are: std::string std::to_string(long long int)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2610: note:                 std::string std::to_string(long long unsigned int)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2616: note:                 std::string std::to_string(long double)
```

(I'm compiling my code with `g++ -std=c++0x`

The method throwing this exception:

```
std::string P1LinkedList::print(){

    std::string print = "";
    iterator itr = begin();

    for(int i = 0; i < theSize; i++){
        print += std::to_string(itr.current->data) + " ";
        itr++;
    }

    return print; 
}
```

`current` is the current Node being pointed to by the iterator.
`data` is an `int` that is within the Node class.

Node.h:

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

struct Node{

        int data; 
        Node* next; 
        Node* prev; 

        Node(const int & d = 0, Node *p = 0, Node *n = 0); 
};

#endif
```

Part of my const_iterator.h file where `current` is declared (my `iterator` class extends from the '''const_iterator''' class:

```
    protected:  
        Node *current; 
        int& retrieve() const; 
        const_iterator(Node*p); 
        friend class P1LinkedList; 
};
```

I'm trying to pass `data` through `to_string` as a regular `int` value, which I thought `itr.current->data` was doing, but could I possibly be getting this error because it's not passing the int value of data, but a pointer to it instead?

Comment: Looks like your implementation has a bug or is not fully C++11 compliant.  gcc 4.4.7 is pretty old and only has experimental C++11 support.  I highly advise you update if you can.  GCC is currently on version 9.2 which is C++17 compliant.

Comment: @NathanOliver unfortunately I'm trying to run my code on my university's class server, which is running 4.4.7. I didn't realize this and wrote my code with an updated version, and now I'm trying to fix it so that it will run on the server :(

Comment: That's a real bummer.  Unfortunately you're going to be limited then. You can use [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11) to see what C++11 features you'll have available but you'll need to have a mix of C++03 and 11 or just stck to C++03 for your projects.  If you are using an updated version at home, you can use `-std=c++03` to force it to use C++03.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you for this! I was wondering how I was going to work on future projects at home with an updated version, this helps a lot

Comment: You could be missing required includes or have various other problems. Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @NathanOliver says is correct, there should be an template instantiation for 'int'. 
The error message basically states, that the compiler is not sure which 'version'(=overload) of the function to use, it has (potentially different) implementations for the input type `long long int`, `unsigned long long int` `long long double`, but you are asking it to operate with an `int`. Again, there should be an overload for int, so this is kind of strange.

What you can do in order to run your program in your current environment, is to use one of the proposed overloads, by casting into int64_t, and hence to use one of the available functions.

```cpp
print += std::to_string(static_cast<long long int>(itr.current->data)) + " ";
```

### Reference:

[here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), you can find a list of the functions that should exist. Be sure to properly `#include <string>` and not to invoke undefined behavior by defining preprocessor macros beginning with `_` operating in std namespace, but I think that is not the issue here.